# Terraform doesn't pick up one certain variable change

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have an ECS Fargate cluster set up that currently has 4 tasks of the same app running on it. The desired number of tasks is defined within a variable:

```
variable "desired_task_count" {
  description = "Desired ECS tasks to run in service"
  default = 4
}
```

When I change the default value to any given number, save it and run `terraform plan` or `terraform apply`, terraform doesn't see any changes. The tfstate file remains unchanged.

```
No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.

Terraform has compared your real infrastructure against your configuration and found 
no differences, so no changes are needed.

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

TFstate:

```
"desired_count": 4,
```

If I change any other variable in that exact same variables.tf file, terraform picks up the changes and applies them.

What I tried to do:

- Create a new variable to pass the value - didn't work
- Rebuild infrastructure with destroy and then apply. This did work as it rewrites a new state file.

TF and provider versions:

```
terraform --version
Terraform v1.2.4
on linux_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.75.2
```

Could this be a provider issue? It seems like the problem only occurs with a viariable that points to a specific setting in a specific resource.
What else can I check?

**SOLVED:**
There was a lifecycle block in the ECS resource that contained a list of change ignores. It was there because of autoscaling, which was temporarily removed from the project.

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [task_definition, desired_count]
  }
```

Comment: The default value is just that a default, if there is a value been passed that is the actual value of the variable, add an output so you can troubleshoot ... also you should provide full code of the resources using the variable in question

Comment: When I edit a variable that contains any other default value required by the aws_ecs_service resource (ie. deployment_maximum_percent), terraform picks it up. "desired_count" is the only one that gets ignored

Comment: Are there any `lifecycle` blocks defined for the task, i.e., are you ignoring changes to some arguments?

Comment: There indeed were Marko, thanks for the hint. Problem solved